# Add data to document using Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firestore and I am having some trouble even though I have gonne through the docs.

I have the following structure:

```
buses (collection) -> cb-123-1 (document) -> many custom objects
```

Now I am trying to add data following the docs:

```
PassengerModel passengerModel = new PassengerModel(
        Integer.parseInt(seatNo.getText().toString()),
        "selected");

mFirestore.collection("buses").document(mBusUid)
        .set(passengerModel, SetOptions.merge());
```

Now the item is added alright on click however it replaces whatever exists in my document instead of adding to it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `PassengerModel` class has all properties for the passenger. In that case the behavior is expected: Firestore loops through all properties of the class. If no value is present for a property, that property is deleted.

You're more likely looking to patch, which requires a data model that only has the properties that you want to modify. An easier and more common approach is to use a `Map` for patches, or this even simpler approach:

```
mFirestore.collection("buses").update(seatNo, Integer.parseInt(seatNo.getText().toString()))
```